# Commutators of the Lorentz generators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lie-algebra

From

$$
U(\Lambda)^{-1} M^{\mu \nu} U(\Lambda) = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\ \rho} \Lambda^{\nu}_{\ \sigma} M^{\rho \sigma}
$$

we get the commutation relations as

$$
[M^{\mu \nu}, M^{\rho \sigma}] = i \hbar \left( g^{\mu \rho} M^{\nu \sigma} - (\mu \leftrightarrow \nu) \right)- (\rho \leftrightarrow \sigma).
$$

My steps so far are the following
$$
\Lambda^{\mu}_{\ \rho} \Lambda^{\nu}_{\ \sigma} M^{\rho \sigma} = (1 +  \delta \omega)^{\mu}_{\ \rho} (1 +  \delta \omega)^{\nu}_{\ \sigma} M^{\rho\sigma}
$$
and to the first order of $\delta \omega$

$$
= M^{\mu \nu} + \delta \omega^{\nu \alpha} M_{\alpha \beta} g^{\alpha \beta} M^{\mu}_{\ \sigma} - \delta \omega^{\alpha \mu} M_{\alpha}^{\ \beta} g^{\rho \beta} M_{\rho}^{\ \nu}
$$
where I used the anti-symmetry of $\delta \omega$. But I am not sure how to proceed from here, the indices does not seems to match to get the desired result.

PS: These are equations (2.14) and (2.16) in Mark Srednicki's book on QFT.

Comment: Just expand $U(\Lambda)$, in the first equation.

Comment: The last expression is wrong, the indices don't match.

Answer (score 1):

Lie algebra depends on the choice of basis.(For example $\Lambda$ matrices in chiral basis are made such that they factorize left and right handed components spinors $\psi$)

$$
(M_{ab})_{ij} = g_{ai}g_{bj} - g_{aj}g_{bi}
$$

$M_{ab}$ are still anti symmetric. $i,j$ denote the matrix element and $a,b$ define a particular generator. Now, the commutation relation can be calculated.

\begin{align}
[M_{ab},M_{cd}]_{xz} &= (M_{ab})_{xy}(M_{cd})_{yz} - (M_{cd})_{xy}(M_{ab})_{yz}\\\\
&=(g_{ax}g_{by} - g_{ay}g_{bx})(g_{cy}g_{dz} - g_{cz}g_{dy}) - (g_{cx}g_{dy} - g_{cy}g_{dx})(g_{ay}g_{bz} - g_{az}g_{by})\\\\ 
&= g_{bc}(g_{ax}g_{dz} - g_{az}g_{dx}) - g_{ac}((-g_{dz}g_{bx}) + g_{dx}g_{bz}) - g_{bd}((-g_{ax}g_{cz})- g_{az}g_{cz}) + g_{ad}(g_{bx}g_{cz} - g_{bz}g_{cx})\\\\
&= g_{bc}M_{ad} - g_{ac}M_{bd} - g_{bd}M_{ac} + g_{ad}M_{bc}
\end{align}